# Waypoints menu highlighting

Tags: jquery, css, smooth-scrolling, jquery-waypoints

I have been trying  to find a way to hightlight my menu icons when user scroll to pass the certain point and I found a way using Waypoints:

```
<script>
    var waypoint0 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById('pagetopAnchor'),
        handler: function() {

            $('a[href="#pagetop"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
        }
    })
    var waypoint1 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById('pagemiddleAnchor'),
        handler: function() {
            $('a[href="#pagetop"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
            $('a[href="#pagemiddle"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
        }
    })
    var waypoint2 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById('pagebottom'),
        handler: function() {
            $('a[href="#pagemiddle"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
            $('a[href="#pagebottom"]').toggleClass('highlighted');
        }
    })    
</script>
```

But I also have a smoothscroll, so when I press the menu icon it scrolls to my desired point, but the waypoints script does not triggers - I have to scroll by myself just a little bit more to see it in action.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it? (So when I press the menu icon it scrolls and toggle the .highlighted class)
I have been trying for a while and couldn't reach the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. 
Sometimes the solution is right under your nose.
Waypoints.js has an "offset" option.

Sorry!

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, do not hesitate to answer your own question. I see you've already done that. However, answer the question so that __others can use the information as well__! See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)